# My coding mistake or problem with the integrity of the data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm learning Laravel from Laracasts videos and so far I've made simple blog with 4 posts that are dynamic but only 2 of them when I click on the name of the post open up the other 2 show error 404 not found

Example of a working one - https://ctrlv.cz/dgUM
Example of a not working one - https://ctrlv.cz/MZrP

web.php code with routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Post;
use Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $files = File::files(resource_path("posts"));
    $posts = [];

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $document = YamlFrontMatter::parseFile($file);

        $posts[] = new Post(
        $document->title,
        $document->excerpt,
        $document->date,
        $document->body(),
        $document->slug
        );
    }
    
    return view('posts', [
   'posts' => $posts
    ]);
});

Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($slug) {
    return view ('post', [
        'post' => Post::find($slug)
  ]);
})->where('post', '[A-z_\-]+');
```

post.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class Post
{
    public $title;
    public $excerpt;
    public $date;
    public $body;
    public $slug;

    public function __construct($title, $excerpt, $date, $body, $slug)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->excerpt = $excerpt;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }
   
    public static function all()
    {
        $files = File::files(resource_path("posts/"));

        return array_map(fn($file) => $file->getContents(), $files);
    }

    public static function find($slug)
    {
        if (! file_exists($path = resource_path("posts/{$slug}.html"))) {
            throw new ModelNotFoundException();
        }

        return cache()->remember("posts.{$slug}", 3600, fn() => file_get_contents($path));

    }
}
```

Comment: you posted the same screenshot twice.  Do you have slug as the primary key on the Post model?

Comment: So your model is not using the database.  Do you have files that match the slug names _exactly_

Comment: @Snapey just checked and i had typo in the slug so it didn't match.. thank you so much again Snapey! One day I wish I will be like you! You just know the solution to every problem haha! Thank you so much again

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `where` filter for the `posts` route is going to work correctly.

1. For regular expressions, in order to be case insensitive, you would need to use `[A-Za-z_\-]+` for the character ranges `A-Z` and `a-z`. If you look at an ASCII table, you can see `A-z` would also include characters like `[ \ ] ^ _` etc.
2. In your second example, your post slug in the url uses a character with an accent mark, I think: `í`. This is not in the regular ACSII alphabet, and is therefore *not* in the range `a-z`. Instead, you can try using the regular expression value `\w` *with unicode mode enabled*, or just `\pL` which will match any kind of letter from any language. If you use the latter, I'd also add `\d` which is equivalent to `0-9`.

So, basically, I think you should change the route's `where` filter to something like this:

```
where('post', '[-_\pL\d]+');
```

Or,

```
where('post', '/[-\w]+/u'); // NOTE: I do not know if Laravel supports adding regex modifiers, so this might not work.
```

Comment: `[-\w]` would be best. `\w` includes underscore and the `-` should be first.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right about it including the underscore. I forgot about that. Either way, I also realized it would actually need to use something like `\pL` because `\w` still doesn't include the accented character.